# $3^n$ as sum of powers of $2$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Is there a closed form to express $3^n$ as a sum powers of $2$? I am interested in the case where all exponents of $2$ are unique.

$$3^0 = 2^0$$
$$3^1 = 2^0 + 2^1$$
$$3^2 = 2^0 + 2^3$$
$$3^n = ?$$

Comment: Probably not, just like there isn't a closed form (an obvious pattern) for $3^n$ (or even $11^n$) in radix $10$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2953601/620957

Comment: What do you mean by a closed form in this context? Any natural number has a unique expression as a sum of distinct power of $2$. But the "form" of this expression comprises a sequence of exponents.

Comment: Here's an illustration of the bits of each $3^n$ for $0 \leq n \leq 32$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ozn6zcqwae

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $3^n = F(n)$, where $F(n)$ is a sum of powers of $2$. Then $$3^{n+1} = 3F(n),$$ from which we get the recursive formula $F(n+1) = F(n) + 2F(n)$. Multiplying by $2$ increases all the exponents by $1$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: It gets complicated when you have a term from the $F(n)$ and one from the $2F(n)$ with the same power - then they combine into a single term of higher power. You can already see this when computing $3^2$ from $3^1$.

Comment: Yeah might be useful for Fibonacci exponents or something as they just FOIL.